# Contact professors who are not listed on application

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, masters

I forgot to include one of the faculty members who works in my area of interest in my application for grad school.

Since I have not mentioned him in my application, would contacting him and requesting a review help my admission?

As far as I know, every professor in the department (CS) could put a review on an application even if he/she is not listed in the potentials. But I think he might ask himself why the applicant did not include his name in his application and simply ignore the review request.

Answer (score 1):

If you really think your application needs a boost you could do this, of course. But you could also contact the professor simply to express interest in the area.

"I am applying to your program and am interested in your area...". But you need to express it so that he knows that you know something about the area.

I wouldn't try to flood the person with information, but you could ask for him to comment on your application and suitability as a student. If he asks for more information, you could send it, but just sending a CV blind is likely to be ignored.

Since the reaction is a matter of personality, there is no way to predict the outcome, of course, but it might be a mistake to appear to be pleading.